# Error when I make a Get Request in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

Whenever I make a Get request on my program, I get the error

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Wrong user name or password [28000-199]
```

I don't have Spring security. My application.properties looks like this

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:C:/Projects/database/demo
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2console
```

As you can see I have no password set, which is weird because when I log into my console I have to log in with user:sa and password:password.

This is the error I get in postman:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-10-15T14:32:53.100+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection",
    "path": "/api/getallcarmakes"
}
```

What is happening? Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the rest of your code. It _seems_ like you need to have your database running based on the error you're getting, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot connect becuase your user/password is incorrect.

If the password is `password` when you log into the console, you should also set this in your application.properties.

So setting `spring.datasource.password=password` should work.

Comment: Ok wow that actually worked, but why the hell was my password 'password' if I changed it to nothing in application.properties??? Thanks so much!

Comment: Specifying the password in the application.properties doesn't actually set the password. The application.properties file is for you to specify what properties Spring should use. So if the password to the db was `password123` then in application.properties you would set `spring.datasource.password=password123`. Hopefully this makes sense.